# How can I change the keyboard layout in SDDM in combination with Wayland and without systemd?

Tags: wayland, void-linux, sddm

I want to change the keyboard layout to *de* (German) for typing my password to login to KDE.

None of the solutions/suggestions I found on the Internet combine the following three parts that I use and thus none of them is applicable AFAICS.

1. Wayland (no setxkbmap)
2. Void Linux (no systemd, thus no localectl)
3. SDDM (no GDM settings)